# Calculating the missing angle

Tags: angle

I have the following problem where I need to find out the missing the angle. I have to apply some triangulation method to solve.

[image: Angle]

I have the values of the hypotenuse.

My solution is to break this triangle into its base and perpendicular considering that 90 degrees is opposite the hypotenuse get the remaining to angles. Is that method correct?

Also the angle x which I have to find is changing with time. How can I incorporate the time changing element.

*Edit with new figure*

I have the lengths a and b and I need to find x. My plan is to find the other two angles using the triangles and subtract those to find x.

Comment: The picture is not very clear. So you say that you know the dimensions of the two triangles? I could label some of the edges with variable names, as well as the two non-labeled angles. What is the angle $x$, exactly? It looks like a 90 angle to me ...

Comment: Consider redrawing the image. It is unclear.

Comment: Just added the new figure. Hope that helps. Its a car and trailer combination and I need to find the angle of the point where the car is connected with the trailer which is x

Comment: So are you saying that you only know the lengths of $a$ and $b$ ? With that information only, we don't know anything about the angle between them. We need more infomation ...